# Dividing a Power of a Prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that the positive integer $a$ divides $p^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer and $p$ is a prime. I want to conclude that $a = p^m$ for some $m \le n$, but I am having trouble. I would appreciate some hints.

Comment: Do you know the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743221) and are you allowed to use it?

Comment: @DavidK Sure. I am allowed to use that.

Comment: Some of the answers use the theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* If a prime $q$ divides $a$, then $q$ divides $p^n$ ando so $q$ divides $p$.

> Therefore, $a$ is a power of $p$ and so $a=p^m$ with $m \le n$.

Comment: Okay, let me see if I follow. Let $ p_1^{\alpha_1} \dots p_k^{\alpha_k} = a$ be the prime factorization of $a$. Since $p_i | a$ for all $i$, then $p_i |p^n$ and therefore $p_i|p$ which implies $p_i = p$. Hence, $a = p^{\alpha_1} \dots p^{\alpha_k} = p^{\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_k}$. Define $m := \alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_k$. If $m > n$, then $a$ couldn't divide $p^n$, so $m \le n$.

Comment: However, I am having a little trouble with your claim, which if I am not mistaken is equivalent to: if a prime $q$ divides $p^n$ and, then $q=p$. Here is my attempt at proof: Suppose that $q|p^n$ yet $q \neq p$. Then $q = kp+r$, where $r \in [0,p)$. Then $q|p^n$ says $p^n = \ell q$ or $p^n = \ell(kp + r)$ or p(p^{n-1}-\ell k) = r$, which says that $p$ divides $r$, which is a contradiction...Does this seem right?

Comment: @user193319, I had in mind this property: If $q$ is a prime and $q$ divides $ab$, then $q$ divides $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Oh, yes. I see. Does my proof work, though?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Factor $a$ into distinct primes.  Which of those primes can divide $p^n$?  How many distinct primes are there in the factorization of $a$, really?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $p^n$ *is* the unique prime factorization of the number $k=p^n$. What form must the divisors of $k$ have then?

Answer (score 0):

If $p,q$ are distinct primes and $n$ is  a non-negative integer then $q\not |\; p^n.$

Proof: Obvious for $n=0.$ If false in general, let $n_0$ be the least $n$ such that $q\;|\;p^n.$ Then $q\;|\;(p)(p^{n_0-1})$ with $n_0\geq 1$ (so $p^{n_0-1}$ is an integer) and $\gcd (p,q)=1.$ So by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic we have $q\;|\;p^{n_0-1},$ contradicting the minimality of $n_0.$

Now if $a\;|\;p^n$ and $q$ is any prime divisor of $a,$ then....?

Answer (score 0):

We can prove this using induction on $n$.

The base case is $n=0$ (I know your problem assumed $n>0$. But this base case is cleaner and the result is a stronger claim). The only positive factors of $p^0 =1$ are $1=p^0$, so the claim is satisfied.

Now suppose there exists $n$ such that every positive factor of $p^{n-1}$ is a power of $p$, and consider a factor $a$ of $p^n$. Write $p^n = ab$. Since $p$ divides the left-hand side, it divides the right-hand side, and so by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#:%7E:text=Euclid%27s%20lemma%20%E2%80%94%20If%20a%20prime,those%20integers%20a%20or%20b.), either $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.

- If $p \mid a$, write $a = pa'$. Then $p^n = pa'b$. Canceling $p$, we have $p^{n-1} = a'b$. By the inductive hypothesis, $a'$ is a power of $p$, which means that $a$ is a power of $p$.
- If $p \mid b$, write $b = pb'$. Then $p^n = pab'$. Canceling $p$, we have $p^{n-1} = ab'$. By the inductive hypothesis, $a$ is a power of $p$.

So the claim is satisfied again, and therefore by induction the claim is true for all $n\geq 0$.